# How to extract "description" tag from a video file info in PHP?

Tags: php, video

Could somebody help me with PHP code to read the description of a `.mov` or `.mp4` video file?

The getID3() does not get the Description information (screenshot attached to show what I want)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the PHP Function: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.id3.php

```
$tag = id3_get_tag( "path/to/example.mp3" );
print_r($tag);
```

Or use this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/

Comment: when i used the method it returns an error "Call to undefined function id3_get_tag()"

Comment: read the installation and activation http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php

Comment: Added further detail on the issue I am facing. Can you please help? Thanks.